# How to place Ant Design Table in parent container bounds under React?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, parent, bounds, antd

I develop a SPA application and I wish place table in parent element bounds but I can't set explicit height. I can set scroll.y of table body but then result total height is large by header height. I can't get header height to calculate total needed height.
How I may place table into parent bounds?

```
<div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh'}}>
<Table scroll={{ y: '100%' }} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}  pagination={false} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
```

Comment: is this works for you? <div style={{ height: "100vh", overflowX: "scroll" }}><Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} /></div>

Answer (score 14):

Seems like it's more of a CSS issue within Ant then a bug. it's a browser limitation.
Try working with `vh` units mixed with `calc`:

### Example:

```
scroll={{ y: 'calc(100vh - 4em)' }}
```

[Related Github discussion](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12088) (require tranlation)

Comment: After almost a year? I don't even remember answering :)

Comment: guys, 100vh is too much in case you have headers and pagination I ended up with 80vh-160px

Answer (score 0):

In React i caculate the height of ant table body then use that as scroll value

```
const [scrollHeight, setscrollHeight] = useState<number>();
const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    if (divRef.current) {
      setscrollHeight(divRef.current.clientHeight - tableHeaderHeight - tableFooterHeight);
    }
  }, []);
```

Replace tableHeaderHeight and tableFooterHeight with your value then the Table like this

```
<Table
            dataSource={data}
            columns={columns}
            pagination={{
              position: ["bottomCenter"],
              defaultCurrent: 1,
              defaultPageSize: 50,
            }}
            scroll={{ y: scrollHeight }}
          />
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting scroll={{ y: '100%' }}, set a number. Because scroll y only takes a number where scroll x takes a number or boolean.

Comment: That's not true. [Docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#scroll) state: *"Set vertical scrolling, can also be used to specify the width and height of the scroll area, could be number, percent value, true and 'max-content'"*

Comment: @vsync, CodingisLife's statement is NOT not true.  He did not say scroll x ONLY takes a number or boolean but that it does take a number or a boolean.  He just didn't included that in addition to these two types it will also accept a percent value and the string 'max-content'.  His main point however is that y only takes a number